# Не работает часть реализации простейшего проекта Spring

Tags: java, spring

Помогите пожалуйста понять, в чем моя ошибка. Ломаю голову уже второй день.
По задумке при переходе на url **/create/new** должна открываться html форма , где нужно ввести **Имя** и нажать на кнопку create, за кулисами должна происходить запись данного имени в условную Базу данных*(ArrayList)* и перенаправлять на страницу **/people** с отображением списка всех людей, находящихся в базе данных.

По факту открывается только страница для записи имени, но при нажатии **create** появляется ошибка 404.

Ссылка на проект:

https://github.com/voiatile/People.git

Если заменить реализацию метода create с такой:

```
@PostMapping()
    public String create(@ModelAttribute("person") People person) {
       
        peopleDao.save(person);
        return "redirect:/people";

    }
```

на такую, то все работает как надо.

```
@PostMapping()
public String create(@RequestParam ("name") String name) {
    People person = new People();
    person.setName(name);


    peopleDao.save(person);
    return "redirect:/people";
```

Answer (score 0):

А может проблема не в коде а в настройке веб сервера? mode_rewrite включен?
файл httpd.conf
Раскомментируйте строку

**#LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**

чтобы стало так

**LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so**

Для включения поддержки файла .htaccess в конфигурационном файле Apache httpd.conf
Найдите

```
<Directory /путь/до/папки/сайтов>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

и измените
**AllowOverride None**
на
**AllowOverride All**

Comment: Не слышал про такой параметр, по умолчанию наверное у меня отключен

Comment: Нужно просто раскоментировать этот параметр в настройках веб сервера

Comment: @GrDEV я в описании вопроса добавил уточняющий момент

Comment: @GrDEV  Почему именно когда использую аннотацию ModelAttribute не работает ?

Comment: Я в jave не сидел. Но друг запускал проект на node.js и ошибка была именно в неверном интерпретироватии строки адреса. Эта настройка решила проблему. По умолчанию веб сервер не понимает адреса типа http://сайт/папка/page Он настроен чтобы понимать адреса вида http://сайт/папка/page.php

Comment: а где этот файл лежит httpd.conf ? я в intellij idea подключаю TomCat сервер

Comment: Ааа, сервер томкат. Там нет этой директивы. Томкат и так должен хавать такие пути.

Comment: Хаха сейчас бы директиву апачевскую в  контейнере сервлетов настраивать